# Avoid ASP.NET postbacks

Tags: asp.net, postback

How to Avoid ASP.NET postbacks?

Comment: Avoid postbacks in general, avoid postbacks in a multiple dropdown scenario, or something else? Please be a bit more specific!

Comment: RichardOD thanks for the interest,how to avoid postback in general?

If I just remove the runat="server" attribute from the Form element,can i avoid postback.

Comment: How you avoid postbacks depends... Where, when and why do you want to avoid postbacks?

Comment: Guffa,but i would like list of possible cases to avoid page postbacks.The question was asked by a supervisor to me and my answer was to use ajax.So would like to know all possible scenario if it could be generalized.thanks

Comment: You don't *want* to always avoid postbacks. It tends to hurt browser navigation, SEO, etc. AJAX is pretty general though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AJAX, UpdatePanels, JQuery:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ should give you a good start.

Comment: yea that is what i was going to say to.. ajax/jquery can perform some tasks without postback.. it depends on you specific situation to.

your situation might be as eazy as

if(!Page.IsPostback) //todo

Answer (score 2):

Asp.NET is entirely based on Postbacks.

May be are you looking for partial page rendering and client side stuffs. If this is the case, you can have a look at [Asp.NET Ajax](http://www.asp.net/ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

Try using html controls if you want to avoid postbacks. ie., it doesn't post back to the server.

What is your exact requirement? You don't want to postback the control or you don't want to feel the postback of a page. If so, you can go for UpdatePanel in asp.net ajax and try using Conditional Update.

Comment: i want to capture all postback scenario including control postback and avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Asp.net MVC3 or MVC4](http://www.asp.net/get-started)  People tend to prefer MVC to webforms